# Input type file, required attribute not working

Tags: c#, html, image, asp.net-mvc-4, required

I am using the MVC 4 framework in my C# project.
I made a page that add ads in my DB (path) and the actual
image in a folder.

The code works but I want to build a safety mechanism that prevents
the page from posting the empty input file (image selector).
I found out that HTML 5 supports the "required" attribute but I still have
some problems left.

When I press the submit button (when there is no image selected)  it marks
the field but the code behind (UploadAd method in UploadController) is still fired.
What is causing this?

Following images and code could make it easier to understand:

View code: http://pastebin.com/s9eWn4zW

Controller code + site validation: http://oi47.tinypic.com/23leeef.jpg

Comment: Can you put a required attribute on your view model so it fails the ModelState.IsValid line? This would still cause it to post, but if you look into MVC Unobstrusive Validation, that could stop it from posting by validating clientside.

Comment: I want to thank You,Shyju and Ismet for your answers.
I found a very easy validation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929186/how-to-prevent-form-submission-while-using-html5-client-side-form-validation-in

Comment: please create an answer and accept it so others can benefit.

Comment: Ow ok, I will do that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You may add the `required` attribute to client side and validate it when user clicks submit.
 Also **You must** do the validation at server side as well. Check whether there is a file exist before saving it

```
foreach(var postedFile in Request.Files)
{
   if (postedFile!= null && postedFile.ContentLength > 0) 
   {
      // good ! Save now
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an extra client-side attribute, called `FileName` which will take place in your `Model` class as follows:

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "You must add a file.")] 
public string FileName { get; set; }

<div class="editor-label">File</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input type="file" //yourCustomAttributes />
    <input type="text" name="FileName" readonly />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FileName)
</div>
```

Add javascript lines too edit `FileName textbox` as a file is selected to be uploded. By this, `client-side controls` will take place and prevent the form to be submitted to your controller if no file is selected.

Answer (score 0):

The ad creation pages uses following form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadAd", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "adForm" }))
{
...
  <div class="editor-label">
            <p>Photo</p>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple required/>
        </div>
}
```

Adding folowing script made it work:

```
<script>
    function manualValidate(ev) {
        if (ev.target.checkValidity()) {
            return true;
        } else { return false;}


    }
    $("#adForm").bind("submit", manualValidate);
</script>
```