# Combining modal popup and HTML5 form validation

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-10

I have a form which does its processing in a modal popup.  I would like the following to happen when the form's button is clicked:

- If a field on the form fails validation, display the validation failure using the browser's native display.
- If the form passes validation, process the modal popup

However I cannot get this to work in IE10. The crux of the problem is:

- If I use buttons of `<button type="button"`, as suggested by the Bootstrap modal popup tutorials, then no browser does its native form validation
- If I use buttons of `<button type="submit"`, then all browsers show the native form validation, however if validation passes, IE10 goes on to reload the page (because it submits the form), aborting the modal popup.  Chrome does not submit the form and correctly shows the modal popup.

My question is: how do I get my desired behaviour in IE10?

---

My code is based on [this tutorial](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/), section *Varying modal content based on trigger button*. Here is the form:

```
<p><form role="form" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="input_opt_name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="input_opt_name" placeholder="Name Here" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Enter the name:">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_window" data-req="blabla">Set Name</button>
</form></p>
```

That code successfully triggers the validation popup ; however in the case of validation failure, the modal popup displays anyway. I added the following code to suppress that, which works:

```
$('#modal_window').on('show.bs.modal', function(e)
{
    var button = $(e.relatedTarget);

    if ( button[0].type == "submit" )
    {
        var tf = button.closest('form');
        if ( tf != undefined )
        {
            if ( !tf[0].checkValidity() )
                e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't been able to make a jsfiddle demo: jsfiddle suppresses form submission so it messes with the issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why Chrome suppresses the form submission but IE10 doesn't. However I have found a workaround (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929186/how-to-prevent-form-submission-while-using-html5-client-side-form-validation-in)).

Adding the following jquery:

```
$('form').bind("submit", function() { return false; });
```

This causes the form submission to be suppressed, without disturbing the modal popup.  This fixes IE10 and does not affect Chrome.