# How to stop Form submit if the validation fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, model-view-controller

UPDATE:
my question is more about `How to prevent the form submit if the validation fails`

the link does not solve my problem

just re-iterate what I'm doing:
I have a form with bunch of input fields and when the user hit the submit button it validate form using attribute `required="required"` if the form validation fails THEN I want to stop submitting the form  as you see the javascript it show the div when the user submit the form.

Hope this clears up.

END UPDATE

How can I stop the form submit to fire if the form validation fails?

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" id="SerialNumber" name="SerialNumber" required="required" type="text">

<button type="submit" name="rsubmit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

 //loading message:
 $("form").submit(function (e) {
     $("#loading").show();
 });
```

Comment: try to `return false;`

Comment: where should i put `return false;`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347282/using-jquery-preventing-form-from-submitting

Comment: thanks for link but the link you have posted is about `preventing form from submitting' but i want to prevent only when the validation fails

Comment: See `checkValidity()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929186/how-to-prevent-form-submission-while-using-html5-client-side-form-validation-in

Comment: The fact that you have attributes `data-val="true"` and `required="required"` suggest your creating this html manually. Use the html helpers - `@Html.TextBoxFor()` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor() so the correct attributes are generated and add the `[Required]` attribute to your property and include the relevant `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` files and this is all handled out if the box.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I able to fixed the problem:

First add the ref on your page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

then do this check:

```
        $("form").submit(function () {
            if ($(this).valid()) {  //<<< I was missing this check
                $("#loading").show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: why so complicated? why to use both jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive ?

Comment: what do you mean by complicated? you mean i can use any one of the .js ?

Comment: no, I just don't know your context, may be you need it for some reason. I'd say with the data given - you don't need it.

Comment: This is **exactly** what I needed. My code has been broken for weeks and users submitting invalid data. I was using this stupid check: `if (!this.checkValidity() || !this.reportValidity())`.

Comment: Simplification: script "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" is not required, "jquery.validate.js" is sufficient

Answer (score 25):

You need to do two things if validation fails, e.preventDefault() and to return false.

For your example, with the input given, the pseudo code might be the next:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
   var validationFailed = false;
   // do your validation here ...
   if (validationFailed) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: This really works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Write your validation code on onsubmit handler of your form like this

```
<form onsubmit="return Validation()">
    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" id="SerialNumber" name="SerialNumber" required="required" type="text">

    <button type="submit" name="rsubmit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

    <script>
        function Validation(){
        //Do all your validation here
        //Return true if validation is successful, false if not successful
        //It will not submit in case of false.
        return true or false;
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: it's not good approach. You have to prevent the form *submit*, not the click on the button. If you'll press ENTER - the form will be submitted outside of your handlers.

Comment: Yes good point. I have changed my code slightly to consider your case.