# How to prevent form submit until all validations are passed [Angular 7]

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-form-validation

I am new to Angular. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263158/angularjs-prevent-form-submission-when-input-validation-fails), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487417/how-to-stop-form-submit-if-the-validation-fails) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347282/using-jquery-preventing-form-from-submitting) question thoroughly, But none of them are of my use as they are using `jquery`. My form is pretty basic registration form with only 4 basic fields. Username, password, confirm password and zipcode and a submit button. To keep this post clean and there are multiple files involved I've uploaded necessary files on github.

1. [**app.component.html**](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/temp-repo/blob/master/app.component.html)
2. [**app.component.ts**](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/temp-repo/blob/master/app.component.ts)
3. [**app.module.ts**](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/temp-repo/blob/master/app.module.ts)

And I am handling validators for `password` and `zipcode` separately in

4. [**validator.ts**](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/temp-repo/blob/master/validator.ts)

Validations are working perfectly fine. But the problem is that the form still gets submitted even when there are validation issues on frontend. Here is my screenshot. Please suggest me a solution or at least give some hint.

PS: I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYwSI1ULjOM) youtube tutorial.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, disable the button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
```

Next, use a condition before submit.

```
  onSubmit(){
    if (!this.form.valid) return;

    // console.log(this.form.controls.zip);
    this.form.markAsTouched();
    console.log(this.form.value);

  }
```

Finally, add that attribute to your form :

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate>
```

Comment: +1 for adding a programmatic validation. I have seen it too often that people simply rely on disabling the button.

Comment: @ak.leimrey did you punch them in the throat ? I would have :D

Comment: I accept this wholeheartedly. I'm so embarrassed I cant even figure out small problems. :-( Thank you @Maryannah.

Comment: @Maryannah I wish. Then again, it makes me feel so smart that I didn't do that and I need every bit of validation, given my limited skillset!

Comment: @Maryannah. Yes Sir. Always.