# Javascript validation form - how to prevent submit on error

Tags: javascript

```
    <form method="post" action="#" id="PasswordResetForm">
                <input type="hidden" name="token" value="toenhere">
                
                <label for="account_password">New Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="account_password" name="account_password" required>
                
                <label for="account_password2">Confirm Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="account_password2" name="account_password2" required>
                
                    <button type="submit">Reset Password</button>
            

<script type="text/javascript">
  function validatePassword() {
  const password = document.getElementById("account_password").value;
  const password2 = document.getElementById("account_password2").value;
  const minLength = 8;
  const hasUppercase = /[A-Z]/;
  const hasLowercase = /[a-z]/;
  const hasNumber = /[0-9]/;
  const hasSymbol = /[!@#$%^&*]/;

  let errorMessage = "";

  // Check for empty passwords
  if (password === "" || password2 === "") {
    errorMessage = "Please enter a password.";
  } else {
    // Check password strength
    if (password.length < minLength) {
      errorMessage = "Password must be at least " + minLength + " characters long.";
    } else if (!hasUppercase.test(password)) {
      errorMessage = "Password must contain at least one uppercase letter.";
    } else if (!hasLowercase.test(password)) {
      errorMessage = "Password must contain at least one lowercase letter.";
    } else if (!hasNumber.test(password)) {
      errorMessage = "Password must contain at least one number.";
    } else if (!hasSymbol.test(password)) {
      errorMessage = "Password must contain at least one symbol.";
    } else if (password !== password2) {
      errorMessage = "Passwords do not match.";
    }
  }

  // Display error message or allow form submission
 if (errorMessage) {
  alert(errorMessage);
  return false; // Prevent form submission
} else {
  return true; // Allow form submission
}
}
document.getElementById("PasswordResetForm").addEventListener("submit", validatePassword);  
    </script>
```

The above form attempts to validate a password field with various rules.

This form should validate the password, but if you get the alert and click OK, the form immediately submits.

I'm scratching my head on this - the "return false" should. just. work., right, or am I missing something?

Comment: try adding event.preventDefault(); in the first line of the function and pass event in the function parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Form submit if the validation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487417/how-to-stop-form-submit-if-the-validation-fails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to prevent the form from submitting if the password's not strong enough, I would use the event argument automatically passed in from the `addEventListener` call to your `validatePassword()` function to call `preventDefault()`.

I assume the reason you thought returning `false` would prevent the form from submitting is because of [this weird behavior](https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/js/javascript-form-onsubmit-return-false/). I used to use this until I got more involved in JavaScript, where I learned about `preventDefault()` and how it plays a lot nicer inside of functions. If you want to learn about the differences a bit more and how to use each one, check out [this article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-stop-form-submission-using-JavaScript).

Otherwise, here's the code you'll need:

#### Snippet

```js
function validatePassword(e) { // Use the event argument passed in from addEventListener() below.
  // ...

  // Display error message or allow form submission
  if (errorMessage) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
    alert(errorMessage);
  } // No need for an else block here, as the form will submit by default
}
document.getElementById("PasswordResetForm").addEventListener("submit", validatePassword);
```

#### Entire Code (Cleaned up a little)

```html
<form method="post" action="#" id="PasswordResetForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="toenhere">

  <label for="account_password">New Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="account_password" name="account_password" required>

  <label for="account_password2">Confirm Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="account_password2" name="account_password2" required>

  <button type="submit">Reset Password</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validatePassword(e) {
  const password = document.getElementById("account_password").value;
  const password2 = document.getElementById("account_password2").value;
  const minLength = 8;
  const hasUppercase = /[A-Z]/;
  const hasLowercase = /[a-z]/;
  const hasNumber = /[0-9]/;
  const hasSymbol = /[!@#$%^&*]/;

  let errorMessage = "";

  // Check for empty passwords
  if (password === "" || password2 === "") {
    errorMessage = "Please enter a password.";
  } else {
    // Check password strength
    if (password.length < minLength) {
      errorMessage = "Password must be at least " + minLength + " characters long.";
    } else if (!hasUppercase.test(password)) {
      errorMessage = "Password must contain at least one uppercase letter.";
    } else if (!hasLowercase.test(password)) {
      errorMessage = "Password must contain at least one lowercase letter.";
    } else if (!hasNumber.test(password)) {
      errorMessage = "Password must contain at least one number.";
    } else if (!hasSymbol.test(password)) {
      errorMessage = "Password must contain at least one symbol.";
    } else if (password !== password2) {
      errorMessage = "Passwords do not match.";
    }
  }

  // Display error message or allow form submission
  if (errorMessage) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
    alert(errorMessage);
  } // No need for an else block here, as the form will submit by default
}
document.getElementById("PasswordResetForm").addEventListener("submit", validatePassword);  
</script>
```